# How to add multiple content to yii2 google maps infowindow?

Tags: php, google-maps, yii2, google-maps-markers

I am using yii2 google maps by 2amigos but I don't know how to add more content in the infowindow popup of the marker.
I want to put multiple images and some description in the infowindow. Right now, I only have one image in it.

```
    $x = 0;
foreach ($dataProvider->models as $model) {
    $marker[$x] = new Marker([
        'position' => $coords[$x],
        'title' => $model->location,
    ]);

    $marker[$x]->attachInfoWindow(
        new InfoWindow([
            'content' => Html::img('@web/'.$model->pic_north,['width'=>180], ['alt'=>'North'])
        ])
    );

    // Add marker to the map
    $map->addOverlay($marker[$x]);
    $x++;
}

echo $map->display();
```

Comment: can you help with it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35891944/add-marker-on-click-maps-2amigos-yii1-and-return-lat-lng-to-put-in-uitextfield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  adding modet img

```
$contentTest =  Html::img('@web/'.$model->pic_north,['width'=>180],
   ['alt'=>'Phil-LiDAR 2.2.13']) .  
   Html::img('@web/'.$model->pic_2,['width'=>180], ['alt'=>'pic_2']) . 
   Html::img('@web/'.$model->pic_3,['width'=>180], ['alt'=>'pic_3']);

 $marker[$x]->attachInfoWindow(
    new InfoWindow([
        'content' => $contentTest,
    ])
);
```

The html helper for img make easly available the options [(see the doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#img%28%29-detail))

this mean you can add the style you need in the helper this way

```
Html::img('@web/'.$model->pic_3,['width'=>180], 
  ['alt'=>'pic_3'], 'left'=>200], ['top'=>120]);
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Another thing, how do I change position of the images?